# Is It Better To Always Return HttpResponseMessage in Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I been wondering this for a while now, is it better to always return `HttpResponseMessage` web using asp.net mvc web api?

When I load up the default webapi project I see they don't use it in the sample controller

```
 // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

I thought the `HttpResponseMessage` wraps everything around and makes it a good Http request. If this is correct what is the benefit of not just using it?

Comment: Because of the extra line Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");???

Comment: Exactly.  If you don't need to customize the HTTP response, it's nicer to stick with simpler code like the sample in your question.

Comment: @SLaks  When the objective is to return a HTTP response, then returning an domain object is not simpler.  It may be easier, but it's definitely not simpler.  But if you really want to return objects, use ServiceStack as it is optimized for that scenario.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I always return HttpResponseMessage.  The point of Web API is to be able to expose an HTTP api.  Pretending that you are returning an object and then relying on the framework pipeline to convert the object to a HTTPResponseMessage is just obscuring the intent IMO.

I am confident that if you pay the extra up front cost of creating the HttpResponseMessage yourself, you will understand better how Web API actually works.  You will run into less problems because you are more likely to avoid Web API doing something you were not expecting.  You will more likely take advantage of HTTP capabilities because the headers are right there for you to access.

Comment: Same I always just return HttpResponseMessage as well but was wondering why other people may choose not to as what I remember reading is it makes a valid HTTP request with all the headers and stuff.

Comment: @chobo2 But there is no way to directly affect the http headers.  You need to create an ActionFilter for any scenario where you want to touch the headers.

Comment: I would also recommend this. We started with a framework about 8 months ago, and a few months back realised how much better it was with HttpResponseMessage. For example (among other good reasons), it allows you to provide "ReasonPhrase" on your response, so you can be more precise if you return "BadRequest".

Comment: Same for me - I always return HttpResponseMessage from any controller methods. It gives me the flexibility of setting response code, message and the actual content (if I need it at all). I can also be sure that if I need to add anything else to the response later on, I can do that without having to modify too much on the controller method.

Comment: @PaulDevenney you can still include a "ReasonPhrase" if you throw an HttpResponseException containing an HttpResponseMessage as demonstrated here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

Comment: Cool, but why doesn't the Web API template in visual studio creates the sample controllers with a return value of HttpResponseMessage? If HttpResponseMessage is always recommended they should have made the template with HttpResponseMessages, don't you think so?

Comment: @BornToCode because it is perceived to introduce complexity.  Many developers don't want to think about the network.  They would rather just pretend they are sending objects over the wire.  Also, some things have change since I wrote this answer, you may be interested in this blog post of mine http://www.bizcoder.com/composing-api-responses-for-maximum-reuse

Comment: +1 for **to avoid Web API doing something you were not expecting**. I hate platforms that trap developers into implicit behavior. I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: @DarrelMiller : Your link in the comment is dead one. Can you please update the latest link?

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 Unfortunately, I'm having issues with that site.  Some people can get to it, some cannot.  It works fine for me.

Comment: @DarrelMiller : Strange issue

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬  It looks like the IP address got blacklisted.  I've got it removed, we'll see if that helps

Answer (score 3):

For separating concerns why not having a service layer (strong typed methods in a class library) and a webservice layer (ASP.NET WEB API ).
The service layer can easily be consumed by Winform, WPF, Console and test projects with no Http dependency and also can be exposed as webservice by ASPNET WebAPi for example for mobile application and/or javascript  .
The webservice Layer concern is to expose the service layer with http concerns (headers, content type, http status..) so you can return HttpResponseMessage.
This also make controller really thin and you can inject the service with DI